# Working with Siege over a proxy

Tags: load-testing, siege

I configured a HTTPS proxy server. Now I want to load test it.
I am trying to use the Siege tool for that but I don't now how can I redirect the whole traffic to my proxy-server , with some no. of users(200) and with around 30 different urls for each user.

Answer (score 0):

`Apache Bench` supports this [How to add http proxy for apachebench(ab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593212/how-to-add-http-proxy-for-apachebenchab)

Otherwise you could use netcat to setup a local proxy to your proxy, http://notes.tweakblogs.net/blog/7955/using-netcat-to-build-a-simple-tcp-proxy-in-linux.html

(yo dawg, I heard you like proxys)

Answer (score -2):

When I test my servers/websites I simply do:

```
siege -c 200 -i -d 15 http://www.url.com
```

It will launch a siege with:

- 200 concurrent users
- internet user simulation
- random delay between 1 and 15 seconds before each request

I don't see the problem to load test your proxy. Maybe i've missed something ?

Comment: The question is about how load test a server using a proxy, not test the proxy itself.

Comment: "I configured a HTTPS proxy server. Now I want to load test it." First two sentences can be confusing... or not. What I understand is that he configured a proxy server and want to load test it. By the way, I don't know why I tried to answer this post.