# How to add http proxy for apachebench(ab)

Tags: proxy, apachebench

I want to grab http packets which ab sends or receives.

So I add a **http_proxy** in shell command:

```
$ export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8888
```

Then I execute ab command:

```
$ ab -c 1 -n 1 http://localhost/
```

Finally, my proxy(127.0.0.1:8888) failed to get http packets from ab.

**Is there any way to let ab access http via http_proxy?**

Here is my environment: **Mac OSX 10.10.3**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read about ab's help `ab -h`, you'll find that it supports an proxy option `-X`:

```
-X proxy:port   Proxyserver and port number to use
```

This option is equivalent of `curl`'s `-x`:

```
-x, --proxy [PROTOCOL://]HOST[:PORT]  Use proxy on given port
```

And it leads to this command:

```
ab -c 1 -n 1 -X 127.0.0.1:8888 http://localhost/
```